# What is @Module annotation in OpenEJB and how it is used?

Tags: java, module, annotations, testng, openejb

I am not understanding the concept behind `@Module` annotation. Documents say, its where you can `setup the code / load the container`. But I am not getting that.

I see that there are set of return types for methods annotated with @Module. But I do not see those methods used anywhere in the code. I am speaking from Testing context.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to running the test the container will invoke the `@Module` annotated methods of the test class and deploy those applications.  Effectively, use `@Module` to build and return the application you want to test.